# Including Invitee Passport to Invitation Letter, Compulsory?

Tags: visas, canada, paperwork, nigerian-citizens, invitation-letters

I have a question I want to ask, I have uploaded the letter of invitation, not a Problem, is there still need for me to have the invitee's data page of his international Passport? Just to make a re-confirmation

[image: ovis.png]

Comment: No, I did not see it there. But i am just wondering

Comment: You are the invitee. The person inviting you is the inviter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The invitation letter must include some proof of the person's legal status in Canada. It can be, but it does not necessarily have to be, a copy of the passport.

The complete [requirements for the invitation letter](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/visit-canada/letter-invitation.html) are on Canada's web site. With respect to proving your inviter's status in Canada, the letter must include:

> - complete name,
> - date of birth,
> - address and telephone number in Canada,
> - job title,
> - whether you are a Canadian citizen or permanent resident,
> - a photocopy of a document proving your status in Canada, such as
>
>   - a Canadian birth certificate, if you were born in Canada,
>   - a Canadian citizenship card, if you are a naturalized citizen, or
>   - a copy of your PR card or your IMM 1000 proof of landing, if you are a permanent resident,

You should include this to the same PDF as the invitation letter itself, when you upload the document.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what i needed to clarify, PR Card. the person inviting me holds a permanent residence for Canada